# Can someone suggest alternative to HdfsSensor for airflow python3?

Tags: python, hdfs, airflow

I am trying to listen to changes in HDFS to trigger my ETL pipeline in Airflow using HdfsSensor in python3. I am getting the following error as snakebite is not supported for python3

**This HDFSHook implementation requires snakebite, but '
ImportError: This HDFSHook implementation requires snakebite, but snakebite is not compatible with Python 3**

Comment: Hi, did you find solution to this?

Comment: @AyushGoyal No. Had to move away from it

Comment: I also used WebHDFSSensor for this task

Comment: @AyushGoyal did WebHDFSSensor solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by @AyushGoyal, I solved the same problem using `WebHDFSSensor`. This sensor looks like `HdfsSensor` and you can just replace the function names. just remember to make sure:

- you pass the connection id via `webhdfs_conn_id` parameter (in HdfsSensor the parameter name was `hdfs_conn_id`)
- the port with which you should try to connect to name node is 50700 (not 8020)

The rest is the same!
example:

```
from airflow.sensors.web_hdfs_sensor import WebHdfsSensor
file_sensor = WebHdfsSensor(
task_id='check_if_data_is_ready',
filepath="some_file_path",
webhdfs_conn_id='hdfs_conn_id',
poke_interval=10,
timeout=5,
dag=dag,
env={
    'JAVA_HOME': '/usr/java/latest'
}
```

)

Comment: there is one more thing that you have to take care when using WebHdfsSensor. In my Case, because of active and stadby namenode I have to pass 2 webhdfs_conn_id for active and standby namenode and using trigger rule one success. So if anyone of them gets success my next dag item will run.